# How to change local file path into ARGF for automatically input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, bioinformatics

I have my local database file in public folder. I would like to open it in my Rails app without running it manually in a terminal. The command requires ARGF (Gem bio) which will work by

In terminal,

```
>> Ruby thiscode.rb database.fasta
```

And in .rb file (Model),

```
 input_seq = ARGF.read       
 my_aaseq = Bio::Sequence::AA.new(input_seq)
```

Or

```
fff = Bio::FlatFile.new(Bio::FastaFormat, ARGF)
```

Then the .fasta file could be iterated.

I did Rails.root.join("public", "database.fasta") and .to_s for input as ARGF but it doesn't work. How can I create ARGF here from local file?

***Additional Detail***

I checked fff variable to see how different between the working one (by ARGF) and not-working one (by local file). In short,

the working one: @io=ARGF and @path=database.fasta

the not-working one: @io = full file path from root join, and @path=nil.

Here are the full differences

work

```
<Bio::FlatFile:0x007fdfb104ef78 @stream=#<Bio::FlatFile::BufferedInputStream:0x007fdfb207a7a8 @io=ARGF, @path="database.fasta", @buffer="">, @dbclass=Bio::FastaFormat, @splitter=#<Bio::FlatFile::Splitter::Default:0x007fdfb1900158 @dbclass=Bio::FastaFormat, @stream=#<Bio::FlatFile::BufferedInputStream:0x007fdfb207a7a8 @io=ARGF, @path="database.fasta", @buffer="">, @entry_pos_flag=nil, @delimiter="\n>", @header=nil, @delimiter_overrun=1>, @skip_leader_mode=:firsttime, @firsttime_flag=true, @raw=false>
```

not work

```
<Bio::FlatFile:0x007fc04ae033c0 @stream=#<Bio::FlatFile::BufferedInputStream:0x007fc0511d3e18 @io="/Users/folder/NAcamp/pt_app/rails_app/Peptool/public/database.fasta", @path=nil, @buffer="">, @dbclass=Bio::FastaFormat, @splitter=#<Bio::FlatFile::Splitter::Default:0x007fc04bdaaf08 @dbclass=Bio::FastaFormat, @stream=#<Bio::FlatFile::BufferedInputStream:0x007fc0511d3e18 @io="/Users/folder/NAcamp/pt_app/rails_app/Peptool/public/database.fasta", @path=nil, @buffer="">, @entry_pos_flag=nil, @delimiter="\n>", @header=nil, @delimiter_overrun=1>, @skip_leader_mode=:firsttime, @firsttime_flag=true, @raw=false>
```